# dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libmkl_intel_lp64.dylib

Tags: macos, perl, shared-libraries, intel, intel-mkl

I tried to run a series of simulations using `gromacs 4.6.5` on MAC PRO in which `intel composer_xe_2013` was installed. If I manually submit an individual job using commands in a terminal, I do not have any problems. However, if I want to submit a series of job using `perl` scripts to run these commands, I always get the error message

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libmkl_intel_lp64.dylib
```

The `$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` has been set and can be visited. I do not know what is going wrong here. Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.